# How do I move a FARPROC's memory address to another Function using ASM?

Tags: c++, c, dll, assembly

I have 2 FARPROCs and I want to replace the address of one with the other using ASM.

What is a FARPROC? "[int (FAR WINAPI * FARPROC) () ] In C, the FARPROC declaration indicates a callback function that has an unspecified parameter list. In C++, however, the empty parameter list in the declaration indicates that a function has no parameters. This subtle distinction can break careless code. Following is one way to handle this situation:"

Now that that's covered, this is my code:

```
  HMODULE h = LoadLibrary("myDLL.dll");
  FARPROC p = GetProcAddress(h, "_GetHelloMessage@0");

  if(!p) MessageBox(hwnd, "injected, but function not found", "Loader", NULL);

  HMODULE dllHmodule = GetModuleHandle("InjectFunctions.dll");
  FARPROC injproc = GetProcAddress(dllHmodule, "_GetHelloMessage@0");

  if(!injproc) MessageBox(hwnd, "injproc is null", "Loader", NULL);

  __asm{
        mov eax, p
        ADD injproc [EAX],8
    }
```

My question is how do I make it so whenever the program that loaded this DLL calls p it will instead call injproc?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do something malicious :)

Comment: It's not malicious to know how to do these things, it's only malicious to use these things for evil, which I plan on not doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each referenced function in an external DLL gets an entry in the Import Address Table in the executable file's header area. Part of that entry is the address of the function. That's what you patch to make the call go somewhere else. There should be plenty of examples on how to do this out on the open internet, though I don't happen to have a link handy.

If you want to do this on your own, download the Portable Executable specification from msdn to see what the format of those headers is.